# how to use two CollectionView on same view controller scroll one by one

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, sigabrt

I would try to set to the collection view on the same view controller, but at runtime it shows the error of signal SIGABRT error so please tell me what can I do to add to the collection view on the same view controller?

Comment: Add exception breakpoint, then update code and the error info.

Comment: get error of datasource & delegate

Comment: Show your error. So that we can understand your issue

Comment: You have a bug on line 192. I can tell that because I am psychic and can read your code from my computer. (That's sarcasm.) We can't possibly help you unless you provide more information.

Comment: Also share the functionality you want to achieve , might be you are designing it in bad way.

Comment: I want to add one horizontal & one vertical collection view on one view controller. Now please tell me what can i do?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You can try as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750108/multiple-collectionview-in-a-uiviewcontroller-ios-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add two collection view in a single view controller by dragging it.

but you have to validate UIcollection view like

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {  
    var cell = HomeCollectionViewCell()

if(collectionView == self.collName1)
            {  
    cell = collName.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell  
}  
else  
if(collectionView == self.collName2)  
{}     
return cell
}
```