# How can i set only one collection view for sizeForItemAt?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I have `ViewController` where have two `collectionView` but for one I want `isPagingEnabled` for cell and for anther `collectionView`  3 item for full frame width. How can I do that ?

MenuCollectionView for paging : it working perfectly

```
 func setupMenuCollection(){        
            if let flowLayout = menuCollectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
                flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            }

            menuCollectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            menuCollectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)
            menuCollectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)

            menuCollectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true

        }
```

It is for manubarCollectionView :  it is not working because here no else statement.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if manubarCollectionView == collectionView {

            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 3, height: manubarCollectionView.frame.height)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where is your second collectionView?

Comment: menuCollectionView and  manubarCollectionView

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simple, for second `collectionView` cell size either add `else block` and return `CGSize` or directly return `CGSize` after `if block`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if manubarCollectionView == collectionView {

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 3, height: manubarCollectionView.frame.height)
    }
    else {
        //return cell size for menuCollectionView
        return collectionView.frame.size
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if manubarCollectionView == collectionView {

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 3, height: manubarCollectionView.frame.height)
    }

    //return cell size for menuCollectionView
    return collectionView.frame.size
}
```

**Note:** You need to put this type of condition in all `dataSource` and `delegate` methods of `collectionView` to differentiate two `collectionView`.

Comment: @cristanlika Check edited answer, to understand clearly and specify with more detail your above comment.

Comment: @cristanlika Is speci.. written is your menuCollectionView's cell?

Answer (score 1):

See Cristan ,

```
menuCollectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0)
```

above method is used for setting space between two cell.

And 
below method collectionViewLayout is used for setting cell Width and Height

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if manubarCollectionView == collectionView {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 3, height: manubarCollectionView.frame.height)  
    }  
    else
    {  
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)  
    }  
}
```

If you want to handle different cell for two collection view then check

[how to use two CollectionView on same view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136994/how-to-use-two-collectionview-on-same-view-controller/37141138#37141138)