# numberOfItemsInSection for multiple UICollectionView inside UIViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have three `UICollectionView` inside one `UIViewController`. Then I set IBOutlet for each `UICollectionView`

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

and I set delegate and datasource for them. But when I want to set `numberOfItemsInSection` like below

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if collectionView == firstCollectionView {
            return 1
        } else if collectionView == secondCollectionView {
            return 2
        } else if collectionView == thirdCollectionView {
            return 3
        }
    }
```

It keeps giving me this error `Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int'`

Comment: add a `return 0` at the end of the function or change the last `else if` to just `else`. You are getting this error because this function doesn't know there are 3 collectionViews. so if none of the `if` statements match then there would be no return

Comment: For better readability, I think you're better off with a switch statement here. You could put the missing `return 0` in the `default` case.

Comment: It solves the problem @Scriptable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple collectionView in a UIViewController - IOS swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28750108/multiple-collectionview-in-a-uiviewcontroller-ios-swift)

Comment: It shows because you not return -> Int for required function, remove third collection view condition from else if and make it only else, error will be solve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return 0 because in `numberOfItemsInSection` you must have to return `Int`. you ended with `else if` but numberOfItemsInSection still need return `Int` value.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView == firstCollectionView {
        return 1
    } else if collectionView == secondCollectionView {
        return 2
    } else if collectionView == thirdCollectionView {
        return 3
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

---

For better readability & a little less code, I suggest you use a `switch` statement:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch collectionView {
    case firstCollectionView:
        return 1
    case secondCollectionView:
        return 2
    case thirdCollectionView:
        return 3
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Thank you for making my answer better :)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd make a separate dataSource class for each collectionView, & assign them in viewDidLoad -

```
firstCollectionView.dataSource = FirstDataSource()
secondCollectionView.dataSource = SecondDataSource()
thirdCollectionView.dataSource = ThirdDataSource()
```

& either give the required data to each dataSource when it's created or make the dataSource have responsibility for getting the data as well. Putting everything into the viewController in a situation like this leads to madness...

Simple example -

```
class MyDataSource: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var data: [MyData] = [] // set this when instantiating, or provide the means of creating the data which you would have put in the viewController

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell: MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        // do stuff to cell
    }
}
```

In viewController -

```
self.firstCollectionView.dataSource = MyDataSource()
// etc...
```

Very straight forward, all it's doing is separating the code into areas of responsibility, makes it a whole lot easier to manage

Comment: How would you implement the data sources?

Comment: Can you pls specifically explain about the separate dataSource with example?

Comment: Nice approach! @SomaMan